# How to create an sObject for a sType without using get_unique_sobject method?

Tags: python, tactic

I wish to create a new sobject for a specific stype.
Currently I am using `server.get_unique_sobject( stype, data)`, But it assumes that an sobject is already present i.e it creates a new sobject ***iff*** there is no combination of sobject with same data **already** existing in the DB.

I wish to create a new sobject each and every time I wish , **even if there is a sobject already present with the same name and data present.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, the API itself provides a method of inserting a sObject to any sType in the system. It was by using `server.insert( sType, data = {})` where data is a dictionary of key value pairs.